# Load a javascript file asynchronously on form submit , before form refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page with a form on it. When i click submit on this form i need to save some data to firebase but the problem is that form when submitted destroys/reloads the whole page before data can be saved to firebase.

Is there perhaps a way to load this saving of data asynchronously somehow so that it can execute in the background or on some other server or something, while the current page reloads.

this is the script i have so far

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    --- save data to firebase ---
}
```

Comment: First, prevent the default action of the form with `event.preventDefault()` then `post` the form using `jQuery.ajax` the function performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request

Comment: thanx Andre for your help,  so jQuery.ajax will load independent of page being refreshed through form submission?   , the problem is form submission "destroys" the whole page and reloads new document  preventing the firebase function to save data.

Comment: if you want to stop the page from submitting before you save your data to firebase, you should use, `event.preventDefault()` , then your code to save the data should follow it. `event.preventDefault()` will stop the form from submitting

Comment: Ok but i do not want to stop the form from submitting , it should look as natural and painless as possible, is it possible to somehow save data without stopping the form?

Comment: yes, what you are trying to do is save a form asynchronously. You will submit the form with `javascript` or `jQuery`, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript for posting with javascript and https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ resource for jQuery

Comment: Andre i would like to recruit you to help me solve this , will pay for your effort, please add me to skype "brandonfan1" if you are interested. thanx.